# return key in python

Tags: function, loops, python-3.x, return

I have my function set up to get inputs from a user! then if the input is correct to return whatever the input was or else keep on looping. however when I do that, when I go to check if x is actually equal to "a1" it tells me its not defined! I don't understand that because I thought that when he returns it, it becomes a global variable!

```
def inputCoordinate():
    list = ("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2","b3", "c1", "c2", "c3")
    while True:
        user = (input("Enter your move: "))
        if user in list:
            return user 
        else:
            print("invalid Coordinates")
            continue 
inputCoordinate()
x=user
```

Comment: you want to use `x = inputCoordinate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how returning and variables work.  `return user` means that the expression `inputCoordinate()` will, when run, evaluate to the value of `user` that was returned, *but no global variables will be created*.  The proper way to do what you want is to just replace the last two lines with:

```
x = inputCoordinate()
```